# popup window to appear in all the activities of the application

Tags: android, android-asynctask, popupwindow

I am creating a popup window in AsyncTask in onPostExecute().It is showing perfectly when i am on the same activity but if I am on the other activity, It doesn't show and the app crashes. I want to make the popup window to appear on whichever activity the user currently is.

As, the layoutinflater has the basecontext of only one activity, that's why it is not showing on other activities. How can I show it on other activities as well.

Here is my popup window code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer progress) {



    View popupView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ImageView btnDismiss = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    ImageView btnDismiss2 = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    ImageView btnDismiss3 = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    btnDismiss2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    btnDismiss3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //   File downloaddirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "Youtube Videos");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getPath()
                    + "/XYZ/");
            intent.setData(uri);
            GlobalDownload.context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(DownloadScreen.intent, "Open folder"));

        }
    });

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);



    }
```

Comment: Popup windows are part of the UI for the activity that shows it.  When the activity becomes invisible, the popup will become invisible with it.  You will have to recreate a new popup for each activity if you want it to persist.

Comment: @DougStevenson : There will still be flicker as a new popup will be created every time after being dismissed. Would appear **very** jarring.

Comment: Right, so perhaps consider an option that doesn't involve multiple activities?  Like multiple fragments?  Or just switching between views?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, it is not possible to share a Popup across all the Activities in your application, as it is attached to the context of the Activity which shows it. One option would to take permission to draw on the window and have a service running constantly, which draws the popup UI over your activities. But, I won't really suggest that.

A cleaner approach would be to use ***multiple Fragments*** instead of multiple Activities. Have ***one single Activity*** which hosts all the Fragments. Display the Popup with the context of the Activity and you would be able to show it across all your Fragments.

Comment: Is there a way to delay the popup window? if I am on the other activity, it doesnt pop up. It just waits for me to go back to that activity and then it pops up? In this way, my app wont crash, if I am on another activity?